# Updating Running Balance

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this table in mysql. I would like to make a php script that will automatically update the balance like the one example B.

```
Example A
----+-------+-------------+---------+
| ID | Debit | Credit     |Balance  |
+----+-------+------------+---------+
|  1 |       | 35         |         |
|  2 | 65    | 0          |         |
|  3         | 35         |         |
|  4 | 65    | 0          |         |
|  5 | 65    | 0          |         |
|  6 | 65    | 0          |         |
-------------------------------------
Example B
----+-------+-------------+---------+
| ID | Debit | Credit     |Balance  |
+----+-------+------------+---------+
|  1 |       | 35         |  -35    |
|  2 | 65    | 0          |   30    |
|  3         | 35         |  -5     |
|  4 | 65    | 0          |   60    |
|  5 | 65    | 0          |  125    |
|  6 | 65    | 0          |  190    |
-------------------------------------
```

Here's what I tried:

```
 $sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_journal 
 ORDER 
  BY date ASC
"; 

$conn = dbconnect(); 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $tbl_id = $row['tbl_id']; 
 $balance = $row['balance']; 
 $credit = $row['credit']; 
 $debit = $row['debit']; 
 echo "<pre>".$tbl_id."*".$row['balance']."</pre>"; 
 $balance = (($balance + $debit) - $credit); 
 $sql = "
UPDATE tbl_journal 
   SET balance = '$balance' 
 WHERE tbl_journal.tbl_id = $tbl_id"; 
$conn->query($sql); 
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yes. But I could not make it work.  Only the first row gets the correct figure.

Comment: Fair enough. Lets start with that. Post what you've tried, we can get it sorted out.

Comment: I don't understand why id = 3 twice !?!

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_journal ORDER BY date ASC";
$conn = dbconnect();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {

  $tbl_id = $row['tbl_id'];
  $balance = $row['balance'];
  $credit = $row['credit'];
  $debit = $row['debit'];
  echo "<pre>".$tbl_id."*".$row['balance']."</pre>";
  $balance = (($balance + $debit) - $credit);
  $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_journal` SET `balance` = '$balance' WHERE `tbl_journal`.`tbl_id` = $tbl_id";
  $conn->query($sql);
 }

Comment: @Strawberry its a typo it should be 4 5 6 7

Comment: Place the additional code in the question mate. It's easier to read.

Comment: `$balance = $row['balance']; ` - in every iteration you overwrite the $balance variable with the value retrieved from the database, which is most likely 0. Take this line out, initialise $balance to 0 before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by initialising a variable, and then using that variable to keep a running total...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,debit INT NULL
,credit INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,NULL,35),
(2,65,NULL),
(3,NULL,35),
(4,65,NULL),
(5,65,NULL),
(6,65,NULL);


SELECT id
     , debit
     , credit
     , @balance := @balance+(COALESCE(debit,credit*-1)) balance 
  FROM my_table
     , (SELECT @balance :=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| id | debit | credit | balance |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 |  NULL |     35 |     -35 |
|  2 |    65 |   NULL |      30 |
|  3 |  NULL |     35 |      -5 |
|  4 |    65 |   NULL |      60 |
|  5 |    65 |   NULL |     125 |
|  6 |    65 |   NULL |     190 |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
```

Actually, the way I've written this is slightly incorrect and can theoretically lead to an error, but in practice I've not yet managed to trigger said error, and I find this way easier to read.

Comment: thank you. Just what I need. Would you mind explaining? :D

Comment: how would I save the balance values in one column?

Comment: @OliverMercado You wouldn't normally store derived data.

Comment: It's not appropriate to edit answers with further questions. I suggest you ask a new question, referencing this one, and with a proper MCVE along the lines described here: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry how do I ask question with reference to this question?

Comment: Just include a link in your next question

Comment: Thanks. If you can help me here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222222/mysql-running-balance-query